# Найти слова в строке и поместить в массив

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток, господа программисты.

Помогите решить проблемку: нужно найти слово в строке начинающееся с двоеточия и занести в массив. Все казалось бы просто, регулярку preg_match_all и все, но не тут то было. Мне нужно, чтобы произошел еще один поиск по этой строке. Если в строке слово начинающиеся с двоеточия встречается и без него, тогда массив на выходе должен быть таким:

array('слово' => ':слово', 'слово2' => ':слово2'),

а если слово встречается только один раз, то есть только с двоеточием, то вместо ключа ставить индекс.

Вот пример:

$stroka = 'Once upon a :time in granny, two gay goose. One  gray :gray, the other white :white. Two happy geese.';

Массив на выходе должен быть таким:
array(':time', 'gray' => ':gray', 'white' => ':white').

Возможно ли реализовать подобное?

Comment: Слова с двоеточием и без идут друг за другом, и именно в таком порядке?

Comment: @PinkTux нет. Идет слово без двоеточия, затем символы чаще всего сравнения и затем идет слово с двоеточием. Что-то типо gray > :gray. Ну, как пример.

Comment: Как это обычно бывает: если решение задачи перерастает в изобретение велосипеда, значит, нужно пересматривать структуру проекта.

Comment: @terron особенно, если автора задачи хватило только на одну регулярку (или по крайней мере упоминание о ней), когда по сути сам подошел к тому, чтобы пройтись еще разок по тексту другой регуляркой: "Мне нужно, чтобы произошел еще один поиск по этой строке."... "где логика, где разум?" (с)

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так?

```
$text = 'Мы пишем какой-то :текст. Время новой планеты настало. Мама мыла раму. Наши поезда - самые поездатые поезда в мире! И никакие поезда других стран не перепоездят наши поезда != :поезда по поездатости.';

$result = checkText($text);

print '<pre>'.print_r($result, true).'</pre>';


function checkText($text) {
    $result = [];
    $pattern = "/(:[\w]+)\b/imsu";
    preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);
    if (!empty($matches[1])) {
        $resultBefore = array_unique($matches[1]);
        foreach($resultBefore as $doublePoints) {
            $flag = false;
            $word = trim(substr($doublePoints, 1));
            $pattern = "/\b($word\s(?:[\s\W]+)?:$word)\b/imsu";
            if (preg_match($pattern, $text)) $flag = true;
            if (!$flag) {
                $result[] = $doublePoints;
            }
            else {
                $result[$word] = $doublePoints;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

P.S. Если мой ответ решил вашу задачу, то отметьте мой ответ как "решение".